# Localization in iphone

Tags: iphone

How to do localization in iphone.

in my current project i have to display my app in 16 languages
all the language domains coming from backend

In the backend php guys using language transition, they are using like this

English:

```
var_name:LOGIN_BTN;
value=Log-in;
```

French:

```
var_name=LOGIN_BTN;
value:Loggain;
```

so for all languages  var_name will be same but value is going to change.
all these var_name and values coming from their database.

the following is the url they have provided me
"http://www.euroclinix.dev-projects.com/mob-web-service.php?action=trans_list&did=29"

did=doamin-id

Answer (score 0):

In general:

For backend/webservice localization you should send your device language to the backend service. Then it should only deliver the needed language.

If that's not possible, you have to get all languages and determine which one to use right on the device.

Comment: How can i send my device language

Comment: i dont know the API you are using, but perhaps they do have a language parameter like **&language=de_de**: `http://www.euroclinix.dev-projects.com/mob-web-service.php?action=trans_list&did=29&language=de_de`

Comment: they have given domain id for each language.there is no language parameter.i am using JSON

Comment: i am displaying desired languages in tableview.Now how to select the language